# Prevent the click event while press the enter key when button in focus in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please advise me, i created a form and press tab key to focus the button. If i press the enter key instead of mouse click event, then jquery events triggers the both keypress and click event. So how can i prevent the click event.

Comment: This is how browsers are designed to consider the usability of the user..

Answer (score 0):

please try this one :

```
$("#ButtonID").keypress(function(e){
   if(e.keyCode === 13){
       e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```