# Enter key fires both click event and keypress when multiple events are attached to button

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, keypress

I have two events attached to a button and when I press a key while the button is on focus both keypress and click events are fired. However, if I click the button only the click event is fired. By adding `e.preventDefault()` seems to fix the issue but I want to understand why it's behaving that way in the first place.
Apologies if this is a duplicate but I couldn't find a relevant answer apart from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582559/prevent-the-click-event-while-press-the-enter-key-when-button-in-focus-in-jquery) but the explanation isn't clear enough there.
Many thanks.

```js
$('.btn').on('click keypress',function(e){
  console.log(e.type);
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn" >click me</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well, i mean, pressing a key causes the button to click, right?  So that's both a click and a key press.  But a mouse click is not a keypress.  It doesn't involve the keyboard at all.

Comment: As you mentioned `e.preventDefault()` resolves the issue - that means it is a default browser behaviour to trigger a click event on a focused item when the 'enter' button is pressed. If you notice, when you press keys other than 'enter' it will only triggers the 'keypress' event

Comment: @ajaiJothi Thanks for the reply - both enter and spacebars fire the event?

Comment: Thanks @Taplar for the explanation - wasn't aware that keypress is treated as a click as well.

Comment: @ConsoleLog Yes, space bar too

Comment: It's not that keypress is treated as a click.  It's that the user interaction causes the **element** to be "clicked".  If you had focus on a link and hit enter, it would also generate a click event for the link.  The important part being what element you are interacting with when the key event happens.

Comment: Thanks very much @Taplar - that's a solid explanation, certainly clarified my confusion!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## On button focus

if you pressed any key **except (space and enter)** only the keypress event will fire

## But

if you **focus** the button and press **space or enter** this will fire both the events because **this is a browser default behavior** also for this same reason `e.preventDefault()` solved the problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @aa-Ahmed-aa Add e.preventDefault() to the click's method or the keydown.enter's method?